# How to configure external IP address of minikube dashboard?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I use docker desktop and minikube on Windows 10. I found the ip address of local docker repository with `minikube docker-env` command like below,

```
> minikube docker-env
SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://172.17.105.232:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\joseph\.minikube\certs
SET MINIKUBE_ACTIVE_DOCKERD=minikube
REM To point your shell to minikube's docker-daemon, run:
REM @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('minikube -p minikube docker-env') DO @%i
```

And I set the ip address of docker daemon with above `DOCKER_HOST` value, not `localhost` and I can use locally built docker images without errors. But in the case of minikube dashboard, the ip address is always localhost(127.0.0.1) when I type `minikube dashboard` command. So I can not generate kubernetes namespace and persistent volume. It throws error

> the server could not find the requested resource

I think this issue is the matter of authorization with different ip addresses. How to configure the static or specific ip address and port number on minukube dashboard so I can generate namespace and persistent volumes without such errors on minikube dashboard?

Comment: output of kubectl version

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually it throws no errors when I use kubectl.exe command. Only minikube dashboard brings such errors.

Comment: maybe you have old version of kubernetes...which you can know by the above command

Comment: I am afraid not. I download the newest version of both minikube and kubectl. The problem is when I use default namespace, the k8s generate the objects successfully. But when generating another namespace or persistent volume, it throws such errors

Comment: what command you run and yamls..can you add it to the question

Comment: In minikube dashboard, as you know the k8s objects are made with graphic user interface. I use dashboard + menu

Comment: Docker-desktop has k8s support and it turns out to be a lot easier to use than minikube

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are trying to access kubernetes dashboard from remote host.
When running `minikube dashboard`, minikube binary runs [`kubectl proxy` command under the hood](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/1a19f8f0a5368f4081a8b3f6f10b2635e043b690/cmd/minikube/cmd/dashboard.go#L130).

By default running `kubectl proxy` binds to loopback interface of your local machine, therefore it can't be accessed from outside.

You can't change minikube cli bahaviour (without changing source code) but what you can do is to note down path to a dashboard:

```
/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

and run `kubectl proxy` by your self adding `--address` paramater with `0.0.0.0` value.

So now running this you will see:

```
$ kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0
Starting to serve on [::]:8001
```

Now open a browser on your remote host and go to:

```
<your-host-external-ip>:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

That's it. Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am afraid the web browser displays 'Forbidden'.

Comment: oh yes sorry, thats because you also need to add `--accept-hosts <your-host-extenal-ip>` to kubectl proxy command, please try this and let me know if its working for you

Comment: The minikube dashboard with my-host-external-ip is working without error. However I can not generate kubernetes namespace and persistent volume. It still throws same error.

Comment: That's because to create namespace you need to change current `Namespace` (left side of a dashboard) to `All namespaces` as Namsepace resource is not namespaced. You can find a list of all namespaced (or not) resources by running `kubectl api-resources` and looking at column called `NAMESPACED`.